# Can external network cards pose a danger to network security?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, security, bluetooth, network-adapter

I want to get an external network card for WiFi and Bluetooth for my PC. A friend of mine advised me to buy one from Asia, since those are significantly cheaper. The difference in actual performance aside, do these cards pose security threads? Is it possible to monitor my network traffic with such a card, and can I detect this?

Comment: "Can external network cards pose a danger to network security?" No more than any other network device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I would say the answer is yes... There is an ever so slightly higher risk than an internal network card. You are probably more likely to be bitten by a shark while being stuck by lightning for this to occur (an exaggeration, but used to get the point across).

But to put that into perspective, it would be almost impossible to exploit that without you knowing it in any attended location because the hacker attempting to compromise your network at this point would have to physically be in the connection between your PC and network adapter. The likelihood of that occurring without being discovered is extremely remote. You are probably more likely to have a hacker to get into a random room and physically plug into a network jack, which would be a multitude of times more dangerous to your network in most cases than someone compromising your adapter.

Answer (score 1):

No. Wireless Security is more governed by strong WiFi password and WPA2 / AES security than by electronics. Quality however is important for long life